# Samsung Galaxy S24 Android 13 Notification Suppression for Children's School

Tags: notifications, remote-control, screenshots, audio-recording

Small non-profit that cares for high-risk children uses stealth recording software on company-owned cell phones that stay on the property to protect the kids. They have legal right, etc.

Cannot find a way to disable the constant notifications now showing anytime a screenshot is taken or sounds are recorded. Many hours online to Samsung already.

Software developers used the following and it works temporarily, but notifiers come back every time phone is restarted:

```
adb shell cmd device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled true default
adb shell cmd device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled false default
```

Can anyone point me in a different direction?

Comment: IMHO Google did a good job in re-enabling those notification icons after a reboot. For 99.99999% of all Android users this is the best way to make malicious apps accessing camera or microphone visible to the user. That some users would prefer having a stealth way to supervise Android users (no matter if legal/legitimate or not) is bad for them but in this case I think the needs of the majority of Android users has a much higher importance.